# PHPUnit error "Failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I just installed PHPUnit Testing and for some reason it won't read my file. I'm sure it's in the correct path, but why PHPUnit can't find it?

Here is my sample code:

functions.php

```
<?php 

 function my_addition($arg1, $arg2){
        return $arg1 + $arg2;

 ?>
```

Here is the code and the file to test:

functions_test.php

```
<?php 


use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;




class functions_test extends TestCase {


public function testmy_addition() {
    include("./data/functions.php");
    $result = my_addition(1,1);
    $this->assertEquals(2, $result);

}


}


?>
```

What can I do to get it to work and make it pass?

Comment: How did you get on with the helpful post below, Michael? It is customary to respond to helpful people in this community, just as it is elsewhere.

Comment: Downvoted (see above).

Comment: @halfer The post was helpful but sometimes we forget to respond and its something that is not on our minds when seeking help from others in this community. We all trying to make everything better.

Comment: OK. I am afraid I see a lot of people who can't be bothered to respond to help when it is offered, and then refuse to do so even when reminded. Thanks for doing so here. I have undownvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use `__DIR__ . "/data/functions.php"` in your include statement
(that's two underscores before and after).

I did a quick test in my test environment and had no problems.

The `__DIR__` magic constant gives you the full path to the test file you are running.  From the PHP website:

> The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of
>   the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   `dirname(__FILE__)`. This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory.