# PHPUnit error “Failed to open stream: No such file or directory”

Tags: php, phpunit

I have same problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060119/phpunit-error-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory). But when i add '**DIR**' as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38060668/10319107), but it working wrong.

my directory structure:

app\Business Logic Layer\searchController.php

app\Data Access Layer\connect.php

app\tests\test.php

test.php

```
<?php
namespace Tests;
require __DIR__.'/Business Logic Layer/searchController.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Search\SearchController as DB;

class SearchTest extends TestCase
{    
    public function testsearch()
    {
        $Ctrl=new DB;
        $result=$Ctrl->select();
        $this->assertNotNull($result);
    }
}
```

When i run phpunit, the console show error

> PHP Warning:  require(F:\xamp\htdocs\AppRoot\app\tests/Business Logic Layer/searchController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\xamp\htdocs\AppRoot\phonebook\tests\test.php on line 3

But my file is F:\xamp\htdocs\AppRoot\app\Business Logic Layer/searchController.php

I dont know how to fix it, please help!

Comment: Just slap print in place of require so that you can see how it’s interpreting.

Comment: The error shows that /tests/ is where you seem to be running this. What command are you running and what folder are you running it in. Try going one directory down and running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was change `require __DIR__.'/Business Logic Layer/searchController.php';`
to `require __DIR__.'/../Business Logic Layer/searchController.php';`

And it is working for me, thank for all help!

Comment: Yes, this worked because your pwd (working dir) was the test dir. Running the test from the main directory also would have worked. Glad you got it fixed, always feels good.

Answer (score 0):

change `require __DIR__.'/Business Logic Layer/searchController.php';`
to `require __DIR__.'\Business Logic Layer\searchController.php';`

Comment: The error shows they are probably running the test from within the tests folder...the dir is showing /tests/ in the error.